# If the Perpendicularity of torque and angular momentum to the plane of rotation is just a conventional definition how does nature know about it?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, vectors, torque

If the fact that torque and angular momentum is perpendicular to the plane of rotation is just a conventional definition how does nature know about this convention in this video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlT30nfjn8

Comment: Does nature know anything about our definitions and conventions?

Comment: There are other ways, such as bivectors, to mathematically represent angular momentum and torque. Nature doesn’t know or care how we represent such quantities. It just “knows and cares” that they exist and have certain relations with other physical quantities. The *relationships* between the quantities matter. Their *representations* do not.

Comment: the definition is consistent and in addition  has useful properties, and allows to solve problems easier. I just works well